# Call a function with the submit button in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, function, form-submit

I need a Google AdWords conversion script to work whenever someone submits a form for a free quote. Google has provided the script which I'm put into a Snippet with WordPress and activated it for the site.

I now need to call that function when the submit button is pressed, but I can't remember the correct syntax and Google searches so far have led me down long paths of .php file creations that isn't answering what feels like a simple solution would solve.

Currently I have added the function in line with the existing code for the submit, but I'm not convinced this is correct. The below code is on the contact form that the page uses.

```
[submit id:submit class:btn class:btn-primary gtag_report_conversion() "Send"]
```

Below is the code I put into the Snippet minus the full "send to" AW address:

```
<script>
function gtag_report_conversion(url) {
  var callback = function () {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  };
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-.....',
      'event_callback': callback
  });
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how that shortcode was implemented, odds are you can't just add inline event handlers to it like that - and without seeing the source code it's hard to determine (but I'd wager that it's most likely the case).

Just add this in the old fashioned way with the [`onclick`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) or [`onsubmit`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp) event handler. I'd recommend the `onsubmit` since forms can be submitted without clicking on the button.

Since you've already loaded in your Script, you can just add to it:

```
<script>
    function gtag_report_conversion(url){
        var callback = function () {
            if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
                window.location = url;
            }
        };
        gtag('event', 'conversion', {
                'send_to': 'AW-.....',
                'event_callback': callback
        });
        return false;
    }

    document.getElementById("your-form-id").onsubmit = function(){
        gtag_report_conversion();
    };
</script>
```

Just replace `your-form-id` with the `id` of your `<form>` element (not your submit button).

Comment: I copied your bit and put in the form ID, but now I'm getting syntax error for unexpected < on Line 1.


  <script>
    function gtag_report_conversion(url) {
    var callback = function () {
      if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
        window.location = url;
      }
    };
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-1...',
      'event_callback': callback
  });
  return false;
}

  document.getElementById("4823").onsubmit = function(){
          gtag_report_conversion();
      };
  </script>

Comment: I'm sorry, that looks horrible. My first time on the site and I didn't realize it would format like that in a comment. 

I also removed the reference to this script from the submit button. I think I see what you are setting up here. If the potential customer is on this specific form and click the submit button, it will get caught by the script.

Comment: This code here specifically I am putting into the plugin Snippets.

Comment: Can you link the one you're using?

Comment: Perhaps letting you see my website helps. 

https://emergenceteleradiology.com/free-teleradiology-quote/


Then the plug in I'm using is Code Snippets
https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/

Comment: It looks like that plugin doesn't allow you to just stick JavaScript in it, it's intended for PHP code (where you would use [`wp_enqueue_scripts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) to properly enqueue that file. You may consider reading through the [`How to include JS/CSS`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) documentation - or use a plugin specifically for putting JS in the header/footer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 ways:

#### Form `onsubmit` attribute

In your form you can add the attribute `onsubmit`:

```html
<form onsubmit="gtag_report_conversion('https://your-optional-callback-url.com')">
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

#### Form `onsubmit` property

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

```js
document.querySelector('#myForm').onsubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(); // To prevent the page from reloading because of the form submission
  gtag_report_conversion('https://your-optional-callback-url.com');
  // ... Other stuff you want to do with the form submission
}
```

#### Form `onsubmit` Event Listener

Same HTML as above

```js
document.querySelector('#myForm').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(); // To prevent the page from reloading because of the form submission
  gtag_report_conversion('https://your-optional-callback-url.com');
  // ... Other stuff you want to do with the form submission
});
```