# How do I launch an onclick function and make it launch another function?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to launch an onclick function when someone clicks a button on my site (has the id of "rum_sst_tab") and then launch another function that counts a google conversion ( `gtag_report_conversion()` )

I've tried some jQuery options for onclick, but they weren't working for me. This is a wordpress site, and id that I'm trying to onclick on, is within a WordPress plugin - not sure if that complicates things or not with this.

```
document.getElementById("rum_sst_tab").onclick = gtag_report_conversion();
```

This is the other part of code that is connected to the gtag function:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-58161224-5"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-72452xxxx');
</script>
```

I'm also getting this error in the console:

> (index):1251 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Comment: We need more code than what you are sharing. We also need to know if you are getting any errors in your console. But, you need to remove the `()` from the end of `gtag_report_conversion` because with them, you call that function immediately, not when the element gets clicked. Event functions should be referenced, not invoked.

Comment: Hi Scott! Thanks for the quick reply! You are right, sorry here is more info, this is the error message I'm getting: "(index):1251 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null" This is the other code connected to gtag_report_conversion(); 

<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-58161224-5"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-724528188');
</script>

Comment: make sure you aren't trying to access the dom before it has rendered

Comment: There's a good change your script is running before the entire web page has been parsed into memory so when your `getElementById()` method runs, it can't find the element. Make sure your script is located just prior to the closing `body` tag in the document to ensure that all the HTML has been parsed before it runs.

Comment: The script is just before the closing body tag, but it still is giving this error of "(index):1251 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null"

Comment: After the page loads, what do you get when you put `document.getElementById("rum_sst_tab")` in the dev console?

Comment: I get the following code:

<a href="https://schedulingapp.mypatientnow.com/Account/Login/1082" target="_blank" id="rum_sst_tab" class="rum_sst_contents rum_sst_right">SCHEDULE ONLINE</a>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Correct way to call your function is:

```
document.getElementById('rum_sst_tab').onclick = 
       function(){
             gtag_report_conversion();
       }
```

(Look: [Call a function with the submit button in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52101029/call-a-function-with-the-submit-button-in-html) )

Note:

> It’s recommended you wait 9-10 hours before checking your conversion rates. This is how long it could take for Google Analytics and Google Ads to begin working together.

(At the final thoughts of https://wpforms.com/how-to-track-form-submissions-as-google-adwords-conversions/)

Comment: It isn't any more "correct" to assign an anonymous function to an event property than to reference a function. In fact, the most "correct" way to do it is with `.addEventListener()`.

Comment: This didn't work, it errors on the site, and displays the code at the very bottom of the page... the actual webpage of the site.

Comment: I looked at the link "Call a function with the submit button in HTML" and I am going to try the code from there! Thanks for your help!